# Dynamically calling show() or attachView() with Marionette

Tags: marionette, backbone-views

Currently, I'm rendering html server-side for my view and using attachView(). However, if that view is closed and later reopened, it seems I need to use show() to re-render it client-side. Also, when instantiating the view (and its subviews) they need to have the $el provided or not.

My thought is to (within the controller) check whether the html element exists in the dom, and dynamically call attachView() if it does or show() if it doesn't.

It seems there has to be a better way and that I'm probably missing something. Does anyone have an elegant way of handling this, either similar to what I've described or entirely different?

Comment: Marionette was not intended to be used server-side. The $el is a jQuery DOM element so unless you want to set up all of that on the server for pretty much no benefit, it's probably best to change your approach and render on the client or just use a template library on the server.

Comment: Can you tell me how you know Marionette was not intended to be used server-side? Is that stated somewhere, or based on your experience? For now what I described in my initial post is what I've done.

Comment: See the first response from Marionette's create, Derick Bailey, [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/383). It's also based on experience. If you look through the code, everything is built for building applications in response to client side events. Without the library responding to all of these events you pretty much removes all of the power of Marionette.